# How do I clear my Facebook status

Tags: facebook, status

I'd like to clear my Facebook status. With the most recent profile changes (December 2010) your status no longer appears at the top of the page with a clear link.

With the new interface how do I clear my most recent status without posting a new one?

What my profile looks like:[image]

the blurred text at the top is just personal data: current location, birthday etc.

Comment: I'm still seeing the "clear" link on my profile page. Is this a change that they're still rolling out?

Comment: @ChrisF I think so. I've added a screen shot.

Comment: Yep - I'm still on the old version then.

Comment: ChrisF - you can force your fbook profile to get the new profile page here - http://www.facebook.com/about/profile/

Comment: @pootzko - I can wait :)

Comment: @ahsteele: as for your status update that you did not blur, check out this article: http://www.allfacebook.com/customize-facebook-profile-2010-12 - how to change what photos appear at the top...

Comment: You look tired.

Comment: @Fosco working while returning to school for another masters will do that to you. :)

Comment: i'm having the same problem. so how do you clear it? or do i need to understand all that code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this Rest item is not deprecated because this is not in Graph API.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/users.setStatus

You can try this http://developers.facebook.com/tools/console/.
This is even assuming you even have a status that can be cleared.

Permissions check

```
<button id="fb-login">Login & Permissions</button>

<script>
document.getElementById('fb-login').onclick = function() {
  var cb = function(response) {
    Log.info('FB.login callback', response);
    if (response.session) {
      Log.info('User logged in');
      if (response.perms) {
        Log.info('User granted permissions');
      }
    } else {
      Log.info('User is logged out');
    }
  };
  FB.login(cb, { perms: 'status_update' });
};
</script>
```

Sanity Check

```
<button onclick="recheck()">Recheck</button>

<script>
window.recheck = function() {
FB.api(
  {
    method: 'users.hasAppPermission',
    ext_perm: 'publish_stream'
  },
  function(response) {
    Log.info('Do we really have permission ?', response);
  }
);
};
</script>
```

Clear the status using user.setStatus

```
<button onclick="clearIT()">Clear</button>
<script>
window.clearIT = function() {
FB.api(
  {
    method: 'users.setStatus',
    uid: 'YOUR USER ID',
    clear: 'true'
  },
  function(response) {
    Log.info('Cleared Status', response);
  }
);
};
</script>
```

Still do not see the sense though. Everyone will eventually be rolled over to the new UI.

**Remember to remove permissions from Rell** (the testing Facebook application) after http://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=applications

--
There is a shorter dirtier way mentioned by Wayne that can be improved on to work.
You could try updating your status.
Then deleting the latest status immediately after.
This should (in theory - I don't think I want to play with my friends like that) work.

Comment: I appreciate the extensiveness of your answer, but I'm not sure it's the best policy for a diamond mod to begin an answer with "You are not making any sense." Unfortunately, that gives a negative connotation to your entire answer. Asking for clarification would seem a bit more appropriate. To further explain my question: in the previous iteration of the Facebook UI your most recent status stayed at the top of your profile and could be cleared. This had the effect of removing the status as "current" but didn't remove it from your wall.

Comment: I clarified the question a bit more.

Comment: @ahsteele Removed whatever may have offended thanks for the clarification, but the situation remains the same. At least to me, I cannot see where the situation would apply apart from having the old UI (which is going to be changed soon, on the off chance they missed this feature that means a total reset of the middle area) and a facebook badge. http://www.facebook.com/badges/profile.php?bid=2326 There you can see the latest status and if it was cleared or not.

Comment: @ahsteele also this is a subset of all your status updates. The status that is collected there, are text only status updates. You can see a list of yours via Graph API or http://www.facebook-me.com/ . Notice those with links or mentions of other users are left out.

Answer (score 0):

Wayne's answer gave me a partial workaround. I just entered a single . or basically any valid character. That'll replace your current status.

Answer (score 0):

Enter any character other than a space and submit. Then immediately remove the post. Crazy, but that seems to be the only way.

Answer (score -2):

Enter a space for your current status? Cheesy workaround if it does the job.

Comment: Um, no. FB sanitizes this bad input.